# ADO.NET Entity Framework and a Joined Subclass

Tags: .net, entity-framework, orm, joined-subclass

Can you do a Joined Subclass in the Entity Framework version 1?
How do you approach the issue?

Joined Subclass:
http://www.xylax.net/hibernate/joinedsubclass.html
http://www.redhat.com/docs/manuals/jboss/jboss-eap-4.2/doc/hibernate/Hibernate_Reference_Guide/Mapping_declaration-joined_subclass.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The Entity Framework calls that "[table per type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738685.aspx)."